# how to change the list i'm saving my values after each loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append

what i want is: when k=0,do all the mathematical stuff for all values of Qs and save it in a list. After that, do the same thing for k=1 and save it in another list etc...

```
Qs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
m =[(10**(-2)), (10**(-2)), (10**(-2)), 1.27] 
e = [2/3, -1/3, -1/3, 2/3] 

psi_T = []
psi_L = []
for i in range(len(m)):
    psi_t = 1 + m[i]
    psi_l = 2 + e[i]
    psi_T.append(psi_t)
    psi_L.append(psi_l)



for k in range(len(psi_T)):
    sigmaT_up = [] 
    sigmaL_up = [] 
    for n in range(len(Qs)):    
        sigmat_up = 2*psi_T[k] + Qs[n]
        sigmal_up = 2*psi_L[k] + Qs[n]
        sigmaT_up.append(sigmat_up)
        sigmaL_up.append(sigmal_up)

    F2up = []  
    for n in range(len(Qs)): 
        F2u = (sigmaT_up[n] + sigmaL_up[n])
        F2up.append(F2u)

print(F2up)
[11.873333333333333, 13.873333333333333, 15.873333333333331, 17.87333333333333, 19.87333333333333, 21.87333333333333, 23.87333333333333, 25.87333333333333, 27.87333333333333, 29.87333333333333]
```

in my code, it keeps replacing the previous values ​​by the values ​​obtained with k=3, (k = 0,1,2,3). I know i gave to the code just one save list (F2up), but i have no clue of how to make it change the save list after each loop.

Comment: Are you trying to save all the F2up lists for each k?

Comment: `F2up = []` You create a new list `k` times. Move `F2up = []` to before the loop??

Comment: i want to do that, but i don't know how... like, do i have to rewrite my list F2up as something like F2up[k] ?

Comment: Johnny Mopp if i move F2up to before the loop it just merges the lists into a larger one. What i want is to create different lists for each k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to create a "master" list where master_list[i] is the F2up list created when k = i.

```py
Qs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
m =[(10**(-2)), (10**(-2)), (10**(-2)), 1.27] 
e = [2/3, -1/3, -1/3, 2/3] 

psi_T = []
psi_L = []
for i in range(len(m)):
    psi_t = 1 + m[i]
    psi_l = 2 + e[i]
    psi_T.append(psi_t)
    psi_L.append(psi_l)

# create master_list
master_list = []
for k in range(len(psi_T)):
    sigmaT_up = [] 
    sigmaL_up = [] 
    for n in range(len(Qs)):    
        sigmat_up = 2*psi_T[k] + Qs[n]
        sigmal_up = 2*psi_L[k] + Qs[n]
        sigmaT_up.append(sigmat_up)
        sigmaL_up.append(sigmal_up)

    F2up = []  
    for n in range(len(Qs)): 
        F2u = (sigmaT_up[n] + sigmaL_up[n])
        F2up.append(F2u)
    # add kth F2up list to master_list
    master_list.append(F2up)

print(master_list)
```